# Attributes Methods in WF

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to do a rehosted workflow. I have a DB with some data providers. All of these, have a provider name and a description. So in my project, I create a class as a provider with get and sets methods for this attributes. 
If is It possible that when I put in the textbox:

```
PROVIDER.
```

Display automatically NAME OR DESCRIPTION as the typical example of:

```
string i;
```

when you do:

```
 i.
```

Appear a menu with Clone, CompareTo, Contains.... methods....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is IntelliSense.

Quick answer: yes, it is possible to do what you want.

That being said, IntelliSense isn't natively supported on rehosted workflow designer. You'll have to implement [IExpressionEditorService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.view.iexpressioneditorservice.aspx) by yourself. It's a pretty complex and comprehensive task for it to work properly.

You can start by reading these posts [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/87064412-406a-4646-a61a-1f316280bda8) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/87064412-406a-4646-a61a-1f316280bda8).

Comment: +1 Although I'd add that custom IntelliSense should also be possible with Roslyn (VS11 Beta only for now).

Comment: That's so much jota. The answer was yes!